# Tkinter button stopped being clickable

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a simple clicking game but whenever I put the code in a `def clicking_game():` and then run it the button that you click to get clicks stops working and can't be clicked but whenever I remove it from the function it works normally.

If anyone knows how to put in a function and keep working normally It would be wonderful if you share!

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import time
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



root = Tk()



root.geometry('450x350')
root.title('Clicking Game')

def clicking_game():

    root.configure(bg='blue')
    level = 1
    clicks = 0
    label = tk.Label(root, text='Experiance: '+str(clicks), background='blue', foreground='white')
    level_label = tk.Label(root,background='blue',foreground='white' ,text='Level: '+str(level))
    photo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\mosta\Downloads\python-transparent-background.png")


    def on_click():
        global clicks
        clicks += 1
        label.config(text='Experiance: '+str(clicks))

        level_label.config(text='Level: '+str(level))




        if clicks >= 10:
            clicks += 2

        if clicks >= 50:
            clicks += 5
            clicks -= 2

        if clicks >= 100:
            clicks += 10
            clicks -= 5

        if clicks >= 200:
            clicks += 20

        if clicks >= 300:
            clicks += 30
            clicks -= 20


        if clicks >= 400:
            clicks += 40
            clicks -= 30


        if clicks >= 500:
            clicks += 50
            clicks -= 40


        if clicks >= 600:
            clicks += 60
            clicks -= 50




    #placing the buttons

    label.pack(side=TOP)
    label.config(font=('Arial', 30, 'bold', 'italic'))
    level_label.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    level_label.config(font=('Arial', 30, 'bold', 'italic'))
    button = tk.Button(root,borderwidth=10,width=60,height=60, text = 'Click Me !', image = photo, command=on_click)
    button.place(x=625, y=300)




clicking_game()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try making `photo` a global variable.

Comment: when I do that the button becomes clickable but when I click it I can't gain clicks

Comment: Also change `global clicks` to `nonlocal clicks`

Comment: Thank you but I already debugged it I had to remove The variable clicks and level from the function def clicking_game()